# Loop over Colums in Pandas Dataframe to create multiple plots with one x variable and mulitple y (colum values)

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I have a single pandas dataframe and want to plot colums 2 though n against colum 1. I would like to create a for loop to do this. I am using matplotlib.

Comment: Questions with code will definitely get the answers here !!!

Answer (score 0):

The [Seaborn](https://stanford.edu/~mwaskom/software/seaborn/index.html) visualization library is based on matplotlib and provides out of the box plot for statistical analysis. I think the `pairplot` function is what your are looking for. See the documentation [here](https://stanford.edu/~mwaskom/software/seaborn/generated/seaborn.pairplot.html#seaborn.pairplot).